# How to set up a time-dependant matrix for an ODE to be solved using python?

Tags: python, ode, scipy, numerical-modelling

I want to solve a problem numerically in python like this:

$$
y(t)' = \mathbf{M}(t)y ,\\ 
y(0) = (1,0,0,0 ...)
$$

where $y$ is an $n$-dimensional vector and $\mathbf{M}(t)$ is a time-dependant $n \times n$ matrix.

The matrix $\mathbf{M}(t)$ is of the shape

$$
\mathbf{M}(t)=
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & T_1(t) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
T_1(t) & 0 & T_2(t) & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & T_2(t) & 0 & T_1(t) & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & T_1(t) & 0 & T_2(t) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & T_2(t) & 0 & T_1(t)\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & T_1(t) & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

or in numpy/scipy notation:

```
[[0. T1 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [T1 0. T2 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. T2 0. T1 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. T1 0. T2 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. T2 0. T1]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. T1 0.]]
```

where $T_1$ and $T_2$ can be arbitrarily time dependant.

My problem is, that for the routine `solve_ivp` in python I need to put in a function of $y$ into the `solve_ivp` routine. I don't know how to create this matrix $\mathbf{M}(t)$ above so that `solve_ivp` can use it.

Has someone some hints or suggestions?

Comment: I edited your question for clarity and presentation. Can you check that I did not make any mistakes?

Answer (score 2):

What about avoiding to construct the matrix by using its structure?

```py
def odefunc(t,u):
    dotu = zeros_like(u)
    T1 = T1func(t)
    T2 = T2func(t)
    dotu[0::2] += T1*u[1::2]
    dotu[1::2] += T1*u[0::2]
    dotu[1:-1:2] += T2*u[2::2]
    dotu[2::2] += T2*u[1:-1:2]
    return dotu
```

This only works if the matrix size is even and not divisible by 4, like the current size 6.